# Struggling with python Comparison question

Tags: python

Am learning python and one of the questions in our study guide asks to evaluate `RNA` sequences. I do not get the expected outputs as suggested by the question, I get `17`.

Here is the code:

```
####START FUNCTION
def rna_length(mrna);
start_rna = 'AUG';

end_rna1 = 'UGA';
end_rna2 = 'UAA';
end_rna3 = 'UAG';

if (mrna[0:3]==start_rna) and (mrna [-3:]==end_rna1 or end_rna2 or end_rna3):
length = len(mrna[3:-3])
return length
else: ((mrna[0:3]!=start_rna) or (mrna [-3:]!=end_rna1 or end_rna2 or end_rna3))
return "Not readable RNA code"

####END FUNCTION
```

A link to a screenshot of the question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ42l.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does `a == x or y or z` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you using the boolean operator `or` to compare strings. You can think of the comparisons like this:

```
(mrna [-3:]==end_rna1 or end_rna2 or end_rna3)
(((mrna [-3:]==end_rna1) or end_rna2) or end_rna3)
```

Because `or` is a boolean operator, it needs to work on booleans. You can convert strings to booleans using `bool(<str>)`

```
(((mrna [-3:]==end_rna1) or bool(end_rna2)) or bool(end_rna3))
```

Any string that is not empty (ie. any string that is not `""`) is "truthy." What that means is that `bool(non_empty_str) == True` and `bool('') == False`.

```
(((mrna [-3:]==end_rna1) or True) or True)
((True) or True)
(True or True)
True
```

Now, how should you fix it? There are a few approaches to this.

1. Properly use `or`.

   ```
    if (mrna[0:3]==start_rna) and (mrna[-3:]==end_rna1 or mrna[-3:]==end_rna2 or mrna[-3:]==end_rna3):
        length = len(mrna[3:-3])
        return length
    else:
        ((mrna[0:3]!=start_rna) or (mrna[-3:]!=end_rna1 or mrna[-3:]!=end_rna2 or mrna[-3:]!=end_rna3))
        return "Not readable RNA code"
   ```
2. Use a collection. Note that it is standard to use tuples instead of lists whenever you don't want to modify the collection. I used lists here because the brackets look different. You can also use sets for quicker `in`, but that's overkill for 3.

   ```
    if mrna[0:3] == start_rna and mrna[-3:] in [end_rna1, end_rna2, end_rna3]:
        length = len(mrna[3:-3])
        return length
    else:
        (mrna[0:3] != start_rna or mrna[-3:] not in [end_rna1, end_rna2, end_rna3])
        return "Not readable RNA code"
   ```

Heck, you can even use the string methods `str.startswith` and `str.endswith`.

```
    if mrna.startswith(start_rna) and mrna.endswith([end_rna1, end_rna2, end_rna3]):
        length = len(mrna[3:-3])
        return length
    else:
        ...
```